# How to build this sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i want to find the records in sql
from say 25-08-2012 to 01-09-2012
and i want to group by date

here is my query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date, 105) AS dt,
COUNT(id) AS cnt
FROM tablename
WHERE date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '21-08-2012 00:00:00:000',103)
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-09-2012 23:59:00:000' ,103)
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date, 105)
```

i am getting result as

```
dt                 cnt
01-09-2012         48
27-08-2012         1
28-08-2012         3
29-08-2012         11
30-08-2012         3
```

but expect it as

```
dt                 cnt
25-08-2012          0
26-08-2012          0
01-09-2012          48
27-08-2012          1
28-08-2012          3
29-08-2012         11
30-08-2012          3
```

How i can modify above query
i also tried with CASE but no luck

Many Thanks..

Comment: what rdbms you are using? also the version.

Comment: databases won't create counts for dates that don't exist. If you want to include zero-count dates, you'll have to create a temp table listing each of those dates and join against it.

Comment: sql server 2005 i dont have records in the table for 25-08-2012 and 26-08-2012 so i want to be as 0 Please suggest if u have aby better solution

Comment: Out of interest, why are you converting some dates to format 103, and some to 105?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are missing these dates in result is that there's no data for them in your table, however, the following would insure you are getting all of the dates in specified range:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_dates ([date] datetime)  

DECLARE @dt_start datetime, @dt_end datetime, @dt_dif int  

SET @dt_start = CONVERT(DATETIME, '21-08-2012 00:00:00:000',103) 
SET @dt_end = CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-09-2012 23:59:00:000' ,103)  
SET @dt_dif = datediff(day,@dt_start,@dt_end)  

WHILE @dt_dif >= 0 BEGIN 
INSERT INTO #tmp_dates 
SELECT dateadd(day,@dt_dif,@dt_start) 
SET @dt_dif = @dt_dif - 1 
END  

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t2.[date], 101) AS dt,  COUNT(t1.id) AS cnt 
INTO #tmp_result 
FROM tablename t1  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN #tmp_dates t2  
ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t1.[date], 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t2.[date], 101) 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t2.[date], 101)   
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t2.[date], 101)) ASC /* DESC */

SELECT convert(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,dt),105) as dt,cnt FROM #tmp_result

DROP TABLE #tmp_dates 
DROP TABLE #tmp_result
```

Comment: Can Please Provide a solution to get order by date

Comment: You would have to change conversion format from 105 to 101 in order to do that (it might not suit your date format though. However, right after `GROUP BY` you would need to add the following: `ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t2.[date], 101)` Don't forget to change 105 to 101 everywhere it mentioned and specify order by direction if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your query cannot be directly modified to return the data you want. To count the dates in question, there must be records in the target table actually having those dates; in your case, however, the dates are merely parameters in the query. As a result, there is no way to incorporate them into your result set.

You must create a secondary table that includes all the dates for which you want data, and then recharacterize your query as a left outer join from that date table to your target table. This will, in turn, give you the zero counts for the dates present in the "date" table, but absent from the target table.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `IsNull()`? Let me know if this works.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date, 105) AS dt,
ISNULL(COUNT(id),0) AS cnt
FROM tablename
WHERE date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '21-08-2012 00:00:00:000',103)
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-09-2012 23:59:00:000' ,103)
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date, 105)
```